# regex + capturing groups with varying conditions

Tags: regex

working on the regex here https://regex101.com/r/wI2cG1/1

this is the data:

```
K'1234567
K'123456789
K'123456
```

I am interested in the digits after K' 
I am looking to do this using regex but not sure if it can be done. What I want is: 
if the number has 6 digits return the first 2 digits e.g. 12 
if the number has 7 digits return the first 3 digits e.g. 123 
if the number has 9 digits return the first 4 digits e.g. 1234

also 
if the number has 10 or 11 digits return the first 3 digits e.g. 123

and I want to return these to different capturing group names or if possible the same capturing group name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to maintain the results in one group using the [branch reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#branchreset) feature:

```
K'(?|(\d{2,3})\d{4}|(\d{4})\d{5}|(\d{3})\d{7,8})\b
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tI2bI7/1)

Comment: tks have I got this right, if I want to return it to the same named `name1` captured group? [here](https://regex101.com/r/wI2cG1/5)

Comment: Yes, If you omit the named group in the other alternatives, the groups will still share the names with the other alternatives.